# PHP for each on the while loop select from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm having trouble with the following code. I want to select from DB first and get some array, after that select from the same table based on each of the elements on the array.

Problem 1: The second select while loop only returns one row from table wheres there are more than one rows matching what i'm selecting. I want to return five rows for each returned row from the first while loop.

Q.1 What's wrong with my code?

Problem two: I'm building an array from a column that has repeating contents. e.g 
returned results might be:

```
[Array]
1.John
2.Cane
3.Mary
4.John.
```

Now when john repeats, i get the same results as the one that was returned at '1'. I know this is expected.

Q2: How do i avoid selecting the same contents in a row?

Notes: i'm aware of the deprecated mysql.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
require_once 'php/db_conx.php';
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE section != ''") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($log)) {
    $LibSection[] = $row['section'];
}
foreach ($LibSection as $Section) {
    $log2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE section = '$Section' limit 5") or die(mysql_error());
    include_once 'php/Random_color.php';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($log2)) {
        echo '<a class="LibSectOpen">
<span style="display:none" class="SectionName">' . $Section . '</span>
<div class="LibrarySects"><div class="LibrarySectsHeader">' . $Section . '</div><div class="LibrarySectsShelf">
<div class="LibrarySectsShelf_Book" style="background-color:' . $Color . '" title="Author: ' . $row['bbookauthor'] . '">' . $row['bbookname'] . '</div></div></div></a>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: use mysql distinct cloumn in your query

Comment: my eyes bleed reading unformatted code :P

Comment: @AwladLiton, that helped a lot. I wonder why ddn't you put that as an answer.

Comment: $`LibSection = array();` would be nice before pushing values to it. Also - no need for 2 loops.

Comment: @Yani How do i kill one loop and still achieve the same results?

Comment: Actually you have 3 loops and you can reduce it to 2. You are using the first `while` loop to populate the array. Instead just use $Section = $row['section'] and avoid your `foreach` loop. Everything inside the foreach will move to the first loop (and change $row to $row2)

Comment: @Yani Can u please use that in the code above so i can accept as an answer if it works?

Comment: Cutting 1 loop will not solve your problem, just will make your code more efficient. Also declaring the array is not a must but both are just good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to choose distinct values so use it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table_NAME where condition=value;
```

possible solution is [W3schools.com- distinct example](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to skip this problem by using MySQL `DISTINCT` operator.

Here is an useful tutorial:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx